# Spring API for Uploading Files (MultiPart) interprets contentType of images as application/octet-stream

Tags: grails, content-type, image-uploading, multipartform-data

Uploading files(images,..) with Spring API(MultiPartFile) works fine on localhost.

However after deployement on Linux Server , the console shows that Spring API interprets contentType of file uploaded such as `application/octet-stream` .,

```
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:449)
    at com.myproject.utils.upload.FileUploadUtil.uploadFile(FileUploadUtil.java:64)
    at com.myproject.utils.GenericFileUploadService$_upload_closure1.doCall(GenericFileUploadService.groovy:56)
    at com.myproject.utils.GenericFileUploadService.upload(GenericFileUploadService.groovy:53)
    at com.myproject.utils.GenericFileUploadService.upload(GenericFileUploadService.groovy:63)
    ... 7 more
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@1723bb6
content.AssetService File instance : org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@1723bb6
println contentType =application/octet-stream
```

Hence , when i use ImagikImage to convert the uploaded file to thumbnail , i get the following error :

```
    `org.im4java.core.CommandException: org.im4java.core.CommandException: convert: unable to open image 
/var/lib/tomcat7/myproject/ROOT/media/5/34:  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587.
```

knowing that the image should be saved normally in the following path

```
 /var/lib/tomcat7/myproject/ROOT/media/5/34.png
```

i found this configuration and i don't know its efficiency:

```
grails.web.disable.multipart=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your file upload form should have an attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, if it doesn't, file contents can be treated as if they were unicode characters and your image files would get corrupted